# Software to increase touch pad functionality in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, software-rec, touchpad

Are there any tools and software for laptop touch-pad to give some additional functionality, like multi touch, clicking on touchpad as screen (touching a location on touchpad will move mouse at same screen location) etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, most of these aren't possible unless the hardware already supports that functionality. If it did, then the drivers generally already expose those abilities. There have been some instances where a laptop vendor used a multi touch capable trackpad and didn't expose the ability in the drivers. It's rare, but in those cases finding appropriate divers from a similar trackpad can work. For absolute pointing ability, the trackpad has to have a high enough resolution to address all the screen's pixels. That's rare enough that I've never heard of it being added to a system that didn't already have it.

If you'd like gesture support, something like [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) might be of use.

Comment: I think If trackpad tells the X,Y location of where the finger is touching it, it can be mapped to screen.

Comment: Even if it does, it's not particularly useful if the resolution of the pad isn't high enough.

Comment: Yes surely it will not be accurate, but it will be still 'something' good.

Answer (score 1):

There was a demo on my PC when I first got it. This demo was only a video showing features of some program that you could by and by doing so you would be able to do many things with your touch pad.

Ex.

If you palmed your touchpad you instantly went to the desktop screen.

Ex#2.

If you used three fingers you could switch between windows by using the fingers on the sides (leaving one finger in the middle) to scroll between windows. If you moved the left finger then the window to the left of the one in use would move to into the screen (in a really cool way not just appearing but actually moving into the screen as if it was taking the spotlight from the previous window).

Well those tools among others. I did not think much of it since I was on a tight budget at the time, but looking back it would have been a great investment. And now I find my self looking for it. It had a name that resembled something of a video player. Virtual ... Something... Don't recall very well.